# Smart Type Completion not working in IntelliJ in a Kotlin/Spring Boot Project

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin, code-completion

I've been working on a Spring Boot Project built using Kotlin language (Gradle, 'idea' and 'kotlin' plugins applied). 
I've been using IntelliJ Ultimate 2017.3.2.

Basic completion works well but Smart Type doesn't : 
[image: Basic completion works but Smart Type completion doesn't]

- Is Smart Type Completion enabled in Kotlin ?
- Does Smart Type completion works well in a java-interop mode (like here with Spring Boot classes from Kotlin) ?
- Is there some settings I don't know to enable it ?

Thanks in advance for your help !